# Wordpress Custom_post slug и чпу

Tags: wordpress, чпу, slug

Есть такая проблема, которую решить не могу уже пару дней.
Все поиски сводятся к одному и тому же…

Вопрос следующий:
Есть необходимость создать новый тип записей для удобства наполнения структуры сайта, это чревато тем, что в урл добавляется **custom_post_slug** от которого я хочу избавиться.

Необходимо сохранить структуру чпу на сайте следующего вида:
site.com/**category**/post_name
site.com/**category/category_child**/post_name

из-за нового типа записей, как ни крути, выходит только так:
site.com/**custom_post_slug**/post_name

**Что я делал**:
Большинство рекомендаций не решают задачу, например заменить slug на '/' - просто уберет из урл.

На сайте wp-kama.ru есть рекомендация при создании нового типа register_post_type() указать для rewrite => slug со значением %category% (регистрировать его не надо, так как он создан по умолчанию)…

> https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type#rewrite
> **slug(строка)**
>  Префикс в ЧПУ (/префикс/ярлык_записи). Используйте array(
> 'slug' => $slug ), чтобы создать другой префикс. В этом параметре
> можно указывать плейсхолдеры типа %category%. Но их нужно создать с
> помощью add_rewrite_tag() и научить WP их понимать.

…но после этого все посты нового типа записей получают 404, и как быть дальше — я не понимаю.

Comment: 1. после создания кастомных типов зайти в настройки пермалинков. 2. Возможно понадобится создать необходимый(е) шаблон(ы)

Comment: я уже и с плагинами мучался, которые дают возможность редактирования пермаинков... все сводится к тому что страницы получают 404, хотя урл выглядит как надо

Answer (score 0):

Решил не вмешиваться в логику работы WP и оставить custom_slug но заменил слово на одну букву, например:

> site.com**/a/category/category_child/**post_name